# Как сдвигать бэкграунд в HTML?

Tags: html

Есть HTML страница и картинка для бэкграунда (в 3 раза шире ширины экрана).
Можно ли ее сдвигать влево и вправо?
И каким образом?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/background-position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
background-position: % %
```

или можно словами

```
background-position: top left
```